# AB load testing on local ip or domain name?

Tags: nginx, load-testing, vps, ubuntu-18.04, apachebench

I am using digitalocean as a vps for my webserver. 
I added a second droplet with ubuntu 18 that is part of the private network (digitalocean function) with the web server.

I am using cloudflare as my dns provider and also using their ssl certificates.

What is the most accurate load test with ab (**please note the http/https in the example below):

```
    ab -n 100 -c 1 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" https://www.example.com/
    Request per second : 12.66

    ab -n 100 -c 1 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" http://www.example.com/
    Request per second : 60.90

    ab -n 100 -c 1 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" https://private.network.local.ip/
    Request per second : 36.70

    ab -n 100 -c 1 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" http://private.network.local.ip/
    Request per second : 1849
```

**How should I use `ab` with `http` or `https` and with domain or local ip?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Well-behaved load test should represent real-life application usage as close as possible, otherwise it doesn't make sense. So you should use the same settings as real users of your application will use, my expectations are:

   - domain name instead of IP address
   - [https](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocol
2. Any reason for comparing response time of your application with the http://example.com which is a live website? You should be comparing [DNS hostname](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-hostnames) of your application with the IP address of your application, in this case the results should be the same
3. [`ab`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) is not the best tool for simulating real users activity, it basically "hammers" a single URL which doesn't represent real user behaviour, real users:

   - establish SSL session once, further communication is being made over this channel
   - send [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) which may trigger [response compression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) reducing response size
   - have [HTTP Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) implemented in their browsers so embedded resources like images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc. are being requested only once
   - have [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) which represent user session

   assuming all above I would recommend switching to a [more advanced load testing tool which is capable of acting like a real browser](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use)

Comment: By "You should be comparing DNS hostname of your application with the IP address of your application" you mean public ip address or private ip address?